# Windows shows "end task window" for my application

Tags: c#, winforms

My WindowsForms application consumes a WCF service to send information to store on my server. It starts to work when Windows starts up and the user logs on. But when the user shuts down the OS, Windows (OS) shows the user an "end task windows" to end the task of my application.

1. Why does windows show me the "end task window"?
2. How can I handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`SystemEvents.SessionEnding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending.aspx) event. You'll probably need to cancel any inflight WCF queries too.

If you already handle this is your `From.Closing` event, you can instead use the following snippet from MSDN:

```
private static int WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x11;

private static bool systemShutdown = false;

protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
    {
        systemShutdown = true;
    }

    // If this is WM_QUERYENDSESSION, the closing event should be
    // raised in the base WndProc.
    base.WndProc(ref m);

}
```

Then in your `Form.Closing` handler you can decide what to do with the system shutdown event coming down the line.